# Using XMPP to connect to facebook & gtalk

Tags: android, chat

when connects first it works but after pressing back button and selecting  other person to chat..app crashes..chat code is following..if more code or explanation is required from my side please suggest:

```
    public class Chat extends Activity{
private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private EditText recipient1;
private EditText textMessage;
private ListView listview;
String recipient;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String recipient = intent.getStringExtra("contentOne");
    String receivedContentTwo = intent.getStringExtra("contentTwo");
    recipient1 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    recipient1.setText(String.valueOf(receivedContentTwo));
    textMessage = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    listview = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    setListAdapter();
    // Set a listener to send a chat text message
    Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String to = recipient;
            String text = textMessage.getText().toString();
             textMessage.setText(" ");
            //Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Sending text " + text + " to " + to);
            Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
            msg.setBody(text);              
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.sendPacket(msg);
                messages.add("you" + ":");
                messages.add(text);
                setListAdapter();
            }

        }
    });

}
public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
    MainActivity.connection=connection;

    if (connection != null) {
        // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
        PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = "you";
                    //String fromName = StringUtils.parseName(message.getFrom());
                    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Text Recieved " + message.getBody()
                            + " from " + fromName );
                    messages.add(fromName + ":");
                    messages.add(message.getBody());
                    //Add the incoming message to the list view
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            setListAdapter();
                        }
                    });
            }
            }
        }, filter);
    }
}
private void setListAdapter() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.simple, messages);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: just tell me that what should i do when back button available on phone is pressed.Actually problem is that this button guides me to listview so if person select other person then chat must b started..but it crashes..